# R Language: change strings in data table to factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a CSV file, containing a column with values either `F` or blank.

After reading importing the table (using R language), I want to change this column to a column of factors, using, `F` value as `Yes`, blank as `No`.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Have you looked at `?factor`? Did you try using the command `factor()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `is.na()` to change the missing values to `No`. Try `factor(ifelse(is.na(data$var) , "NO", "YES"))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use `mutate` and `case_when` functions.

```
## load libraries
library(dplyr)

## create data.frame
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), values = c('F', '', 'F', 'F', 'F', '', 'F', 'F', '', 'F'))

## modeling data
df <- df %>% mutate(values_replaced = case_when(values == '' ~ 'No',
                                                TRUE ~ 'Yes') %>% as.factor())
```